# Save cell separated csv file in vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv, file-format

I have an Excel sheet with two columns, like this:

```
53400   10
53480   1
53470   1
53460   1
53450   1
53440   1
```

I would like save a new `.csv` file using a vba macro:

```
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
Worksheets("CSV").Range("A:B").Copy

Workbooks.Add

ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Worksheets("CSV").Range("A:B").ClearContents
```

The problem is that I get a `.csv` file comma separated, like this:

```
53400,10
53480,1
53470,1
53460,1
53450,1
53440,1
```

And what I want is a a `.csv` file with one value in each cell, like the original data (I can get something like this saving manually):

```
53400   10
53480   1
53470   1
53460   1
53450   1
53440   1
```

Comment: A `.csv` file haven't any cell !!! what do you want exactly? An Excel sheet ?!

Comment: I understand what you say, but if you save manually a file as a .csv (macintosh) in Microsoft Excel, you get a file without commas, but separated with cells. I upladed a sample file here: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/libro1)

Comment: I found the answer: the problem was the list separator. I had to use ";" instead of ",". I could configure it by adding `Local:=True` when saving the workbook. You could also force the list separator to be ";" using another command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the list separator. I had to use ";" instead of ",". I could configure it by adding Local:=True when saving the workbook. You could also force the list separator to be ";" using another command.